# How can I test if my concurrency limiting is working in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using throat npm to limit concurrency and I'm wondering how I can test if it's actually working? Like my code runs fine, but how can I be sure it's actually limiting?

This is my code:

```
const throat = require('throat');

readURLsfromFile().then( (urls) => {

    Promise.all(urls.map(
        throat(1, (url, i) => {
            main(urls[i], i, urls.length)
        }))
    );
})
```

Edit: I tried Tushar's idea but I can't get it to work. Maybe I'm not using throat properly? Here's the code I'm trying:

```
const throat = require('throat')(1);
var request = require('request');
let counter = 0

throat(() => {
    counter++
    console.log(counter, 1)
    main(1).then( () => --counter)
})
throat(() => {
    counter++
    console.log(counter, 2)
    main(2).then( () => --counter)
})
throat(() => {
    counter++
    console.log(counter, 3)
    main(3).then( () => --counter)
})


function main(i) {
    return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
        request("http://google.com", (err, response, html) => { 
            resolve()
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Store the number of executions on a variable outside scope, then whenever you have your `main` function running you `++` the counter, when its over you `--` it. You can then check out that variable to know at a given time how many concurrent executions you are performing.

Answer (score 1):

simple set a counter

```
let counter = 0; // set the counter to zero
const throat = require('throat');

readURLsfromFile().then( (urls) => {

    Promise.all(urls.map(
        throat(1, (url, i) => {
            counter++;
            console.log(counter, i); // print counter value and i
            main(urls[i], i, urls.length);
        }))
    );
})

function main (..........) { ....... --counter;  } // decrement the counter value once task is completed
```

if counter always prints 1 i.e only one process is running at a time.

Comment: You'll need to `--` the counter as well eventually.

Comment: @JuanStiza yeah `--` is a better option, updated answer.

Comment: @Lansana which bug?

Comment: If `main` were to return a `Promise`: `main(urls[i], i, urls.length).then(() => counter-- );`

Comment: @TusharGupta Your bug was the `counter = 0` line, when you were supposed to be decrementing. But you have now changed it to `--counter`. Just teasing, though.

Comment: I tried something but I can't get it to work. I updated my post with my new code. Do you know what's wrong with it? @TusharGupta